# This container service is in a failed state

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

All of our AKS clusters have the following error reported in Azure Portal:

> This container service is in a failed state. Click here to open a new support request.

[image]

It seems we also cannot edit the cluster.  When trying to scale out the nodes, I am getting the following error:

> Failed to save container service 'test-aks'. Error: Operation is not allowed while cluster is being upgrading or failed in upgrade

When looking into the AKS properties, I see there is a provisioning state of "Failed":

[image]

We don't know how to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: I'd contact support and go to #sig-azure on k8s slack

Comment: Did you do any changes to your cluster recently like upgrading to another version?

Comment: Use the az aks scale command to scale the cluster nodes using Azure CLI as described here and share the results: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/scale-cluster#scale-the-cluster-nodes
It is likely that you exceeded the core quota. Let me know.

Comment: Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: It was because I submitted an update request to the cluster, but there were no vCPUs available in my subscription. This set the state of the provisioning update to "Failed", but with no reasoning. I had to increase my quote and rerun the update command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the issue that you shows:

> This container service is in a failed state. Click here to open a new
>   support request.

It also happened to me. Usually, there is some limitation to the user for the use of resources. On my side, I just can use 10 vCpu. So I got the error when I scale up for more nodes if the vCpu have none left. I think it's also a possible reason for you. You can take a check.

Comment: It was because I submitted an update request to the cluster, but there were no vCPUs available in my subscription.  This set the state of the provisioning update to "Failed", but with no reasoning.  I had to increase my quote and rerun the update command.  Thanks

Comment: @davenewza You mean you increase the quote and it works? Maybe it's the limitation of other resources. You can get more details from the log.

Answer (score 2):

Use the az aks scale command to scale the cluster nodes using Azure CLI as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/scale-cluster#scale-the-cluster-nodes

az aks show --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --query agentPoolProfiles

This will show you the descriptive error message in Azure CLI. **It is likely that you exceeded the limit for the core quota.** 
More details discussed on this thread: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/542